# Angular linky without sanitize (filter)

Tags: angularjs

New to angular.  I'm using the linky filter to add href links to some already-sanitized text, with line breaks in it.

http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky
[angularjs newline filter with no other html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964735/angularjs-newline-filter-with-no-other-html/13979292#13979292)

```
<section class="description"
       ng-bind-html-unsafe="piano.description | noHTML | newlines | linky ">
</section>
```

However, linky automatically sanitizes the html, removing my carefully added newlines.  There doesn't seem to be an accepted way of doing this, what would work well?  Make a filter to unescape my linebreaks?  Customize linky to add a no filter option?

Comment: Care to add a plunker?

Comment: Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/JzVPGq?p=preview

Comment: In the source file, it looks like there's support for something called "validElements", but no mention of how it's supposed to be used. :-/ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-sanitize.js

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue myself today - solved it eventually by replacing Angular's internal linky-filter with parseUrlFilter from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693341/2199358

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question in the title. Use angular's linky without the sanitize. I just went into Angular's source, copy-pasted angular's linky function without the sanitization, and renamed it.

Full code here:

[Angularjs directive to replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692640/angularjs-directive-to-replace-text/24291287#24291287)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the following directive in a similar circumstance.  It does two things:

1. No HTML Sanitization
2. The markup is compiled in the current scope.

Usage:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in newItemHTMLs" replace-with-html="row"></tr>
```

Source:

```
myApp.directive('replaceWithHtml', ['$parse', '$compile', function($parse, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var ngBindHtmlGetter, ngBindHtmlWatch;

        ngBindHtmlGetter = $parse(tAttrs.replaceWithHtml);
        ngBindHtmlWatch = $parse(tAttrs.replaceWithHtml, function(value) {
          return (value || '').toString();
        });
        $compile.$$addBindingClass(tElement);

        return function(scope, element, attr) {

          $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.replaceWithHtml);

          return scope.$watch(ngBindHtmlWatch, function() {
            return element.replaceWith($compile(ngBindHtmlGetter(scope))(scope) || '');
          });

        };

      }
    };
  }
]);
```