# Keep line breaks in HTML string

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Angular 5 and Firebase, I am storing and retrieving movie review information. When creating and editing the review, line breaks are kept (I assume using an ngModel has something to do with this). However, when retrieving the review from a reader's perspective, the `ReviewComponent`, the line breaks are not kept. Logging the body still shows the line breaks and using Angular's `json` pipe shows as `text\n\ntext` showing where the line breaks should be.

Here is my HTML:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">{{review.body}}</p>
</main>
```

I have also tried `span` and `body`.

How can I keep these line breaks in the review for the reader?

Comment: What are you using for creating and editing the reviews, a standard `textarea` element or a third-party rich text editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs newline filter with no other html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964735/angularjs-newline-filter-with-no-other-html)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

HTML, in general, uses `br` tags to denote a new line. A plain `textarea` tag does not use this, it uses whatever the user's system uses to denote a new line. This can vary by operating system.

Your simplest solution is to use CSS

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;white-space:pre-wrap;">{{review.body}}</p>
</main>
```

This will maintain any "white space" formatting, including additional spaces.

If you want to actually replace the newline characters with `br` tags you can use the following regex

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;" [innerHTML]="review.body.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')"></p>
</main>
```

**Edit** Thanks to ConnorsFan for the heads up on replace not working with interpolation.

Comment: Did you try the second solution? I think it works with `[innerHTML]` but not with interpolation. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-sqx1fq).

Comment: I forgot to mention: it doesn't seem to work with regular expressions either, but it works when replacing a string. The syntax available in the template is somewhat limited.

Comment: What is `margin-bottom: 2rem` for? Consider removing from the code if irrelevant

Comment: @AntonDuzenko, it is part of the code in the original question. There is no reason to remove it as it would serve a purpose for the original author.

Answer (score 26):

by using the `[innerText]` directive the white spaces seem to be maintained, as well as the `\n` new lines

e.g. `<small style="display:block" [innerText]="review.body"></small>`

Comment: I'm pulling the text from a DB, so `[innerHtml]` seemed susceptible to JS injection. Using `[innerText]` works great for just maintaining white space for me.

Comment: I see that using `[innerText]` results in Angular (or the browser) converting the new-line characters into `<br>` tags.

Comment: For Angular, this is the solution

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation where I had HTML code like this:

```
<div>{{msgTitle}}</div>
```

And I tried putting both `'\r\n'` and `&lt;br&gt;` in the string `msgTitle`, but neither of them worked to put a newline in the text displayed on the page. This link gave me the solution:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7781

Use `[innerHTML]="msgTitle"` instead of `{{msgTitle}}`.

Answer (score -5):

try span but set it like that:

```
span 
{ 
    display : table;
}
```

it should helps.